# What does this do/ produce? [ ] [ ]

Tags: r, function, indexing

I have a piece of code:

```
change <- round((table_subset$positive[1][1] - avg) * 100 / table$positive[1][1], 2)
```

but I am not sure what the [1][1] parts are doing/ what they are calling. Can someone explain this to me or if there is another way to do it?

Comment: could you provide the result of `dput(table_subset$positive)`?

Comment: Read `help("[")`. Study `str(table)`.